# Getting "Undefined symbol for architecture arm64" error while building Swift project with Objective-C framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I'm making iOS application with usage of JabberGuest framework from Cisco. I've followed their instruction (provided [here](https://developer.cisco.com/site/jabber-guestsdk/documents/guest-ios-dev-guide/v11_2_3/)) with necessary adjustments. While building, compiler returns almost 100 errors, all around `undefined symbol`. Core of the application is written in Swift.

Part of error log below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "std::__1::recursive_mutex::recursive_mutex()", referenced from:
      csf::edge::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter() in JabberGuest(IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter.o)
  "std::__1::recursive_mutex::~recursive_mutex()", referenced from:
      csf::edge::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter() in JabberGuest(IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter.o)
      csf::edge::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter::~IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter() in JabberGuest(IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter.o)
      csf::edge::IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter::~IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter() in JabberGuest(IpInterfaceChangedEventFilter.o)
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long) in JabberGuest(regex.o)
      boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, long) in JabberGuest(regex.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::underflow()", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::re_detail_106501::parser_buf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > in JabberGuest(instances.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::pbackfail(int)", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::re_detail_106501::parser_buf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > in JabberGuest(instances.o)
[...]
JCFCoreUtils::EncryptionUtils::privateKeyDecryptToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, csf::SecureString const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in JabberGuest(EncryptionUtils.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, char)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail_106501::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::append_set(boost::re_detail_106501::basic_char_set<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, mpl_::bool_<false>*) in JabberGuest(instances.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(ObjectFoundry.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(ObjcLibraryLoader.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(FileUtils.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(UnifiedFactory.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(ServicesDispatcher.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(Base64FamilyEncoder.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in JabberGuest(TaskDispatcher.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My header looks like this:

```
#ifndef _ltProjectName_gt_Bridging_Header_h
#define _ltProjectName_gt_Bridging_Header_h
#import "Frameworks/JabberGuest.framework/Headers/JabberGuest.h"

#endif
```

In build setting, I have `Framework Search Path` correctly set, `Objective-C Bridging Header` for both `Debug` and `Release` set on correct file, added `VALID_ARCHS` on `armv7 arm64`, `Architectures` set on `Standard Achritectures (arm64 armv7)`. All the necessary libraries are linked in `Link Binary With Libraries`.

I've tried cleaning Xcode and cache, adding `$(inherited)` to `Other Linker Flags`, set `Yes` to `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)`. There are no pods in use nor any other 3rd party frameworks.

I'm checking if the project builds right now, without implementing any of methods in other files, so there are no more changes in my project.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Looks like the C++ Standard Library is not linked/has an incorrect version. Are you sure that you switched "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)"?

Comment: Yes, `C++ Standard Library` is set to `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `libc++.dylib` is not linked to the project.

1. Select the project file
2. select the target
3. Select the Build Phases sub-tab
4. Under Link Binary with Libraries press the `+` button
5. Select `libc++.dylib` and press Add

Another option is to try to add `-lc++` to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.